# Javascript match: return only subpattern matched contents

Tags: javascript

```
"unescape('awefawef')unescape('efawefwf')unescape('awefawef')"
.match(/unescape\(\'([^\)]+)\'\)/gi)
```

If there multiple `unescape(...)` matches it returns matches with `unescape`, but i need only what is inside `()` brackets.

Thanks ;)

Desired output:

```
['awefawef','efawefwf','awefawef']
```

Comment: Sure, added to the main post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the ungreedy operator to match only the contents of the parenthesis, and to get all results, you will need to call RegExp.exec multiple times on the same string.

```
var regex = /unescape\('(.+?)'\)/ig;
var string = "this unescape('foo') is a unescape('bar') test";
var result;
while(result = regex.exec(string))
    console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: Could you please give some link about ungreedy operator for javascript regexp? Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't specific to JS but applies to it:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy

Comment: Hmm why .match method is not working with this ungreedy operator?

Comment: It does. The only problem with match is that it won't keep returning matches every time you call it. It will either only give you the first, or all of them but with the pattern included, depending on the global flag's presence.

Comment: Aha thanks for docs. Got it now. Because i was confused about ? sign. Because i remember that it had another purpose. But if it's placed after + or * it becomes related to them.

Comment: If you've found one of the given answers helpful, please consider accepting it as the answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from `RegExp.$1`.

```
"unescape('awefawef')unescape('efawefwf')unescape('awefawef')".match(/unescape\(\'([^\)]+)\'\)/gi);
console.log(RegExp.$1); //awefawef
```

Comment: Wow cool, didn't knew that. But isn't that global anyhow? And what with the rest matches?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use capturing, you can use Regex.exec(). Using your case:

```
var str = "unescape('foo')unescape('bar')unescape('baz')";
var regex = /unescape\(\'([^']+)\'\)/g;

var result;
while( result = regex.exec(str) ){
    alert(result[1]);
}
```

Edited: Fixed up original answer

Comment: Yea it seems better to loop exec until required result or until exec returns null. Thanks ;)